# Is possible to convert multiple if <n in interval> into an array?

Tags: python-3.x

Code like this

```
def IsEven(n):
    if n%2==0:
        return "Is even"
    else:
        return "Is odd"
```

can be converted to a function like this

```
def isEven(n):
    return ["Is even","Is odd"][n%2==0]
```

The question is if code like this:

```
def intervalsToOutput(n):
    intervals=[(x1,x2), (x3,x4), (x5,x6), ... (xn,xn+1)]
    if x1<=n<=x2:
        return "in first interval"
    elif x3<=n<=x4:
        return "in second interval"
    elif x5<=n<=x6:
        return "in third interval"
    ...
    elif xn<=n<=xn+1:
        return "in last interval"
```

... can be replaced **efficiently** with a function like this:
(assuming the intervals (xi,xi+1) are not overlapping, and are sorted by xi)

```
def intervalsToOutput(n):
    intervals=[(x1,x2), (x3,x4), (x5,x6), ... (xn,xn+1)]
    answer=["in first interval","in second interval","in third interval",...,"in last interval"]
    return answer[index of (n in Interval)]
```

The best I made (**looking for speed**) is

```
def intervalsToOutput(n):
    intervals=[(x1,x2), (x3,x4), (x5,x6), ... (xn,xn+1)]
    answer=["in first interval","in second interval","in third interval",...,"in last interval"]
    import bisect as bisect
    return answer[bisect.bisect_left(intervals, (n, )) - 1]# -1 because it is a zero based list
```

What bisect_left does is to find the position of n in intervals (in O(log(n)) time) by comparing (n,) with (xn,xn+1)
But the purpose of bisect is to find the insertion place, so it fails for any n which is x_{i+1}<n<=x_{j}

... (x_i, x_{i+1}),   (x_j, x_{j+1}) ...
**[x_i______x_i+1]**   fails on this interval  x_j **[________x_j+1]**

---

**EDIT:**
This is a solution using intervaltree instead of bisect, but it has some overhead, because intervaltree returns a set, which may be empty
(I also accept faster/more elegant solutions based on this code)

```
#generate intervals and answers
import random
min=0
max=20
numIntervals=6

def Intervals(min,max,n):
    randInts = random.sample(range(min, max), n * 2)
    randInts.sort()
    return [(x1,x2) for x1,x2 in zip(randInts[::2], randInts[1::2])]

intervals=Intervals(min,max,numIntervals)
answer=[f"In {n}th interval" for n in range(len(intervals))]

#Implement solution

import intervaltree

tree = intervaltree.IntervalTree() 
[tree.addi(i[0],i[1],a) for i,a in zip(intervals,answer)]

def intervalsToOutput(x):
    answer=tree.at(x)
    if len(answer)>0:
        return answer.pop().data
    return "value not found"

print(intervals)
[print(f"{x} is ",intervalsToOutput(x)) for x in random.sample(range(min,max),numIntervals)]
```

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
intervals=[(1,2),(6,8),(22,45),(101,110)]

tgt=27
idx=next(i for i,t in enumerate(intervals) if t[0]<=tgt<=t[1])

>>> idx
2
```

If you want to catch a not-found condition, either use `try / except`:

```
try:
   idx=next(i for i,t in enumerate(intervals) if t[0]<=tgt<=t[1])
except StopIteration:
    # not found
```

Or use the default form of `next`:

```
idx=next((i for i,t in enumerate(intervals) if t[0]<=tgt<=t[1]), None)
```

---

Fair point regarding this method being slow. Here is a monumentally faster way.

You can take the source of [bisect](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/bisect.py) and modify with custom logic to inspect each tuple in the list see if the condition of `t[0] <= x <= t[1]` and return `None` if that condition cannot be satisfied.

Given a list of tuples of this form:

```
[(0, 3), (5, 10), (13, 17)] ... [(69735, 69739), (69742, 69746), (69749, 69752)]
```

You can have a custom bisect search to find a tuple that satisfies the condition stated:

```
def bisect_search(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None or hi>len(a):
        hi = len(a)

    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        f_mid=-1 if x<a[mid][0] else 1 if x>a[mid][-1] else 0
        if f_mid < 0:
            hi = mid
        elif f_mid > 0:
            lo = mid + 1
        else:
            return mid
        
    return None
```

Here is a benchmark for those two methods:

```
import random 
import time 

def gen_tuples(cnt, span=(1,5)):
    li=[]
    
    lo,hi=0,random.randint(*span)
    
    for _ in range(cnt):
        li.append((lo,hi))
        lo=li[-1][-1]+random.randint(*span)
        hi=lo+random.randint(span[0]+2,span[-1])
        
    rando=random.randint(cnt//2,cnt-1)
    to_find=li[rando][random.randint(0,len(li[rando])-1)]   
    return (rando,to_find,li)



def next_(a, x):
    return next((i for i,t in enumerate(a) if t[0] <= x <=t [1]), None)
    
def bisect_search(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None or hi>len(a):
        hi = len(a)

    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        f_mid=-1 if x<a[mid][0] else 1 if x>a[mid][-1] else 0
        if f_mid < 0:
            hi = mid
        elif f_mid > 0:
            lo = mid + 1
        else:
            return mid
        
    return None


def cmpthese(funcs, args=(), cnt=1000, rate=True, micro=True):
    """Generate a Perl style function benchmark"""                   
    def pprint_table(table):
        """Perl style table output"""
        def format_field(field, fmt='{:,.0f}'):
            if type(field) is str: return field
            if type(field) is tuple: return field[1].format(field[0])
            return fmt.format(field)     
        
        def get_max_col_w(table, index):
            return max([len(format_field(row[index])) for row in table])         
        
        col_paddings=[get_max_col_w(table, i) for i in range(len(table[0]))]
        for i,row in enumerate(table):
            # left col
            row_tab=[row[0].ljust(col_paddings[0])]
            # rest of the cols
            row_tab+=[format_field(row[j]).rjust(col_paddings[j]) for j in range(1,len(row))]
            print(' '.join(row_tab))                
            
    results={}
    for i in range(cnt):
        for f in funcs:
            start=time.perf_counter_ns()
            f(*args)
            stop=time.perf_counter_ns()
            results.setdefault(f.__name__, []).append(stop-start)
    results={k:float(sum(v))/len(v) for k,v in results.items()}     
    fastest=sorted(results,key=results.get, reverse=True)
    table=[['']]
    if rate: table[0].append('rate/sec')
    if micro: table[0].append('\u03bcsec/pass')
    table[0].extend(fastest)
    for e in fastest:
        tmp=[e]
        if rate:
            tmp.append('{:,}'.format(int(round(float(cnt)*1000000.0/results[e]))))
            
        if micro:
            tmp.append('{:,.1f}'.format(results[e]/float(cnt)))
            
        for x in fastest:
            if x==e: tmp.append('--')
            else: tmp.append('{:.1%}'.format((results[x]-results[e])/results[e]))
        table.append(tmp) 
        
    pprint_table(table)                    
    
    
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    print(sys.version)
    cases=(
        ('small, found', True, 100),
        ('small, not found', False, 100),
        ('large, found', True, 10000),
        ('large, not found', False, 10000)
    )
    for txt, f, cnt in cases:
        rando,to_find,li=gen_tuples(cnt)
        tgt=to_find if f else -1
        args=(li, tgt)
        f1,f2=bisect_search(*args), next_(*args)
        print(f'\n{txt}: {f1}, {f2}')
        cmpthese([next_,bisect_search], args)
```

Prints:

```
3.10.2 (main, Feb  2 2022, 06:19:27) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)]

small, found: 84, 84
              rate/sec μsec/pass  next_ bisect_search
next_          121,533       8.2     --        -82.0%
bisect_search  675,074       1.5 455.5%            --

small, not found: None, None
              rate/sec μsec/pass  next_ bisect_search
next_          155,885       6.4     --        -81.6%
bisect_search  847,744       1.2 443.8%            --

large, found: 8824, 8824
              rate/sec μsec/pass    next_ bisect_search
next_            1,232     811.9       --        -99.6%
bisect_search  299,677       3.3 24230.9%            --

large, not found: None, None
              rate/sec μsec/pass    next_ bisect_search
next_            1,524     656.0       --        -99.6%
bisect_search  340,112       2.9 22211.5%            --
```

Which shows that the `bisect_search` method is substantially faster.

Note: It is tempting to try and use the the `key` in Python 3.10 bisect to do the same thing. This is not possible since the upper end of the range of the target tuple is not known and the method of `(x,)` is only comparing to the bottom of the range of the target tuple.

Comment: Might make sense to use `-1` instead of `None`

Comment: But `-1` is still a valid index for the last element.

Comment: Is faster than Intervaltree

Answer (score 1):

Well here's one way, but don't do this (for readability, and probably performance). You should really just chain `if`,`elif`,and`else` statements (or use a `for` loop):

```py
def really_esoteric(n):
    return ["first", "second", "n"][
        [n in range(0,10),
         n in range(11,16),
         n in range(16,30)].index(True)
        ]
```

REPL:

```py
>>> really_esoteric(5)
'first'
>>> really_esoteric(13)
'second'
>>> really_esoteric(20)
'n'
```

---

Another way of going about this:

```py
from bisect import bisect
def search_ranges(n, intervals):
    # Get the index on an insertion
    index = bisect(intervals, (n,))
    
    # Get the low and high values for the interval
    lower_low, lower_high = intervals[index - 1]
    upper_low, upper_high = intervals[index % len(intervals)]

    # Test if n is in the interval
    if n in range(lower_low, lower_high):
        return f"{n} in {intervals[index-1]}"
    elif n in range(upper_low, upper_high):
        return f"{n} in {intervals[index]}"
    else:
        return f"{n} not in an interval"

print(search_ranges(0, [(0, 10)]))
print(search_ranges(4, [(0, 10)]))
print(search_ranges(11, [(0, 10), (11,20)]))
print(search_ranges(12, [(0, 10), (15,20)]))
print(search_ranges(19, [(0, 10), (11,20)]))
print(search_ranges(11, [(0, 10), (11, 20), (21, 30)]))
```

Outputs:

```
0 in (0, 10)
4 in (0, 10)
11 in (11, 20)
12 not in an interval
19 in (11, 20)
11 in (11, 20)
```

Comment: it's O(n), which is the same as writing all the ifs

Comment: @Colim ah I see what you mean, one moment

Comment: @Colim There you are, O(log(n))

Comment: print(search_ranges(11, [(0, 10), (11, 20), (21, 30)])) returns "11 not in an interval"

Comment: @Colm trivial to fix just check the other side ill fix when im back at my desk

Answer (score 0):

Are the intervals random? i.e. if the range is 0-10 and each there are 5 intervals (0-2)(2-4)(4-6)(6-8)(8-10)

Just do something like

```
def func(n):
    spacing = 2
    return n // 2
```

Comment: No. The intervals are sorted by the first element of the tuple, with varied length, and are non overlapping